# Routes not working correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

**EDIT:** Thanks for the replies, I tried everything listed below but still now luck. If I type localhosts/posts/new it takes me to the form, however the link does not work when I click from the navigation bar. I've updated the code and included my rake routes results.

I am new to ruby and working through a tutorial, however one of my links is not working and not sure what is happening.

My navigation link to create a new post is not taking me to the correct page, when I click the link to the "posts_path" the page does not change.

I can create a new posts by typing in the /posts/new in the address bar, but when I click the "New Post" link on the nav bar the page does not update (although the url displays /posts).  Any idea how to fix this?

config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
get 'sessions/new'
root 'static_pages#home'
get  '/search', to: 'static_pages#search'
get  '/login', to: 'sessions#new'
get  '/posts', to: 'posts#new', as: 'new_post'
post  '/login', to: 'sessions#create'
delete  '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
get  '/signup', to: 'users#new'
get 'users/new'
get 'static_pages/home'
get 'posts/new'
get 'sessions/new'
resources :users
resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
resources :password_resets, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
resources :posts, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
end
```

app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
<div class="container">
  <% link_to "sample app", root_path, id: "logo" %>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Search", search_path %></li>
          <% if logged_in? %>
            <li><%= link_to "Users", users_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Posts", posts_new_path %></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
             <a href='#' class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Account <b class="caret"></b></a>
             <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Logout", logout_path, method: "delete" %></li>
             </ul>
           </li>
           <% else %>
             <li><%= link_to "Log in", login_path %></li>
           <% end %>
          </ul>
       </nav>
  </div>
```

posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
    before_action :correct_user, only: :destroy

    def create
            @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
            if @post.save
                    flash[:success] = "Post created!"
                    redirect_to root_url
            else
                    @feed_items = []
                    render 'static_pages/home'
            end
    end

    def destroy
            @post.destroy
            flash[:success] = "Post Deleted"
            redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
    end
    def new
       @post = current_user.posts.build if logged_in?
    end

    private

    def post_params
            params.require(:post).permit(:description, :picture)
    end

    def correct_user
            @post = current_user.posts.find_by(id:params[:id])
            redirect_to root_url if @post.nil?
    end
end
```

rake routes:

```
password_resets_new     GET     /password_resets/new(.:format)          password_resets#new
password_resets_edit    GET     /password_resets/edit(.:format)         password_resets#edit
sessions_new            GET     /sessions/new(.:format)                 sessions#new
root                    GET     /                                       static_pages#home
search                  GET     /search(.:format)                       static_pages#search
login                   GET     /login(.:format)                        sessions#new
new_post                GET     /posts(.:format)                        posts#new
                        POST    /login(.:format)                        sessions#create
logout                  DELETE  /logout(.:format)                       sessions#destroy
signup                  GET     /signup(.:format)                       users#new
users_new               GET     /users/new(.:format)                    users#new
static_pages_home       GET     /static_pages/home(.:format)            static_pages#home
static_pages_about      GET     /static_pages/about(.:format)           static_pages#about
static_pages_search     GET     /static_pages/search(.:format)          static_pages#search
posts_new               GET     /posts/new(.:format)                    posts#new
                        GET     /password_resets/new(.:format)          password_resets#new
                        GET     /password_resets/edit(.:format)         password_resets#edit
                        GET     /sessions/new(.:format)                 sessions#new
help                    GET     /help(.:format)                         static_pages#help
about                   GET     /about(.:format)                        static_pages#about
contact                 GET     /contact(.:format)                      static_pages#contact
users                   GET     /users(.:format)                        users#index
                        POST    /users(.:format)                        users#create
new_user                GET     /users/new(.:format)                    users#new
edit_user               GET     /users/:id/edit(.:format)               users#edit
user                    GET     /users/:id(.:format)                    users#show
                        PATCH   /users/:id(.:format)                    users#update
                        PUT     /users/:id(.:format)                    users#update
                        DELETE  /users/:id(.:format)                    users#destroy
edit_account_activation GET     /account_activations/:id/edit(.:format) account_activations#edit
password_resets         POST    /password_resets(.:format)              password_resets#create
new_password_reset      GET     /password_resets/new(.:format)          password_resets#new
edit_password_reset     GET     /password_resets/:id/edit(.:format)     password_resets#edit
password_reset          PATCH   /password_resets/:id(.:format)          password_resets#update
                        PUT     /password_resets/:id(.:format)          password_resets#update
posts                   POST    /posts(.:format)                        posts#create
                        GET     /posts/new(.:format)                    posts#new
post                    DELETE  /posts/:id(.:format)                    posts#destroy
```

Comment: I can't see new post link in your header file.

Comment: `rake routes` will help you

Comment: Did you tried the recommendations that i mentioned ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails scans the routes from top to bottom **i.e. routes.rb**. Whenever it finds the matching routes corresponding **controller#action** gets executed and remaining all will be skipped(later routes after match found).

In this case routes are conflicting, So do bellow changeseverything will work fine.
    config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
get 'sessions/new'
root 'static_pages#home'
get  '/search', to: 'static_pages#search'
get  '/login', to: 'sessions#new'
#get  '/posts', to: 'posts#new', as: 'new_post' #not required as resources :posts will do the job in last line
post  '/login', to: 'sessions#create'
delete  '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
get  '/signup', to: 'users#new'
get 'users/new'
get 'static_pages/home'
get 'posts/new', to: 'posts#new', as: 'posts_new_path'  #Made changes here according to helper used in view 'posts_new_path'
get 'sessions/new'
resources :users
resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
resources :password_resets, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
resources :posts, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove `get 'sessions/new'` & `get  '/posts', to: 'posts#new', as: 'new_post'`

Restart server

and try `link_to "Posts", new_post_path, method: :post`

Should work

Comment: Wouldn't the path helper be `new_post_path`?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you remove `get 'posts/new'` & `get  '/posts', to: 'posts#new', as: 'new_post'` as these are duplicate routes.

You already have the correct route created in the route `resources :posts, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]`. By including `new`, Rails is doing this portion for you. See here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions

Then you should be able to use the link that everyone else has posted. 
`<%= link_to "New Post", new_post_path %>` based on the guide here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers

Answer (score 2):

The problem is there is conflict occurring in your routes.
You have defined routes twice for `new`

```
get /posts', to: 'posts#new', as: 'new_post'
```

and

```
resources :posts, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
```

now there are 2 paths for `posts#new`. I suggest u **remove** first one. Change your **html** to

```
<li><%= link_to 'New Post', posts_path %></li>
```

and it should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

i went through your code...and this is what i recommend to add/edit changes..and sure it should work :).

1. for `routes.rb`,its looks good `BUT`
    there is a **duplicate** url entry.So either remove `get 'posts/new'` or `resources :posts, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]` as they both will create a duplicate entry for `posts#new`.You can verify this by outputting your routes in seperate txt file by `rake routes >> path.txt`
2. in `app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb`,its good too and dont need any change.
3. in `posts_controller.rb`,**there is a condition added for only logged in user**,Kindly check if you are logged in else remove that condition and check again.
4. Finally,debug using `F12` in chrome/firefox and see what log do you get in web browser console **before** and **after** click to check is there some javascript error or not.

Answer (score 1):

code for link to new post

```
<%= link_to "New Post", new_post_path %>
```

Comment: To brief and vague. Pls explain how it solves the questioner's problem and relates to the post.

Answer (score 1):

Try `new_post_path`

Also, `rake routes` in terminal will list all the routes and associated helpers for you to double check against.

Finally, adding 'as' to: `get  '/posts', to: 'posts#new', as: 'new_post'` in your routes file will allow you to define your own path name (in this case new_post_path, but you can set it as anything you'd like).

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= link_to "Posts", posts_path %> corresponds to index action not to the new action.
```

Remove the only condition for your posts controller in routes.rb which will create all the basic routes needed rather than specific routes.

```
resources :posts
```

So, new_post_path returns /posts/new

Finally add a link link `<%= link_to 'New Post', new_post_path %>`

Answer (score 1):

This may be helps to redirect,
in **routes.rb**,

```
resources :posts
```

It gives the paths to all default controller methods like index, new, create, edit, update, show, destroy. Then check with rake routes. Get the corresponding path like,

```
new_post GET      /posts/new(.:format)                    posts#new
```

if it correct means give the url like,

`<%= link_to 'New Post', new_post_path %>`
It redirects to method new in controller and render corresponding html.erb page. This url formed by the routes.rb.

**OR**

push the redirection url manually.In html page,

```
<%= button_tag "New", :onclick => "getNew()" %>   
function getNew(){
        var form = document.forms[0];
        // get the id and value with any variable // 
        form.method = "post";       
        // pass the value to parameters //
        form.var name = column name; (description r picture) 
        form.action = "posts/new";
        form.submit();
    }
```

in routes.rb,

```
match '/posts/new' => 'posts#new', via: [:get, :post]
```

It makes the manual redirection url. It calls the new in controller method.
Let me know your feedback! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As per your rake routes output the following should work

```
<%= link_to "New Post", posts_new_path %>
```

Please let us know whether there any error comming in the console log on clicking the new post link.

Answer (score 1):

The bottom line is that you're trying to do things in a non-Rails manner. Rails favors **convention over configuration**, meaning if you don't do things the Rails way, you're going to have a bad time.

This means you should clean up your routes until you have no unnecessary duplication. Right now you have 3 different routes that go to `posts#new` each with a different path prefix.

I'd remove:

- `get  '/posts', to: 'posts#new', as: 'new_post'`
- `get 'posts/new'`

since `resources :posts, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]` already creates that route. Then your `new_post_path` helper should create the correct URL and your routes will have no ambiguity.